# Where should I mount the engine management electronics in a 1993 Ford Mustang?

Tags: ford, interior, mustang, computer

Bought myself a 1993 Ford Mustang (2.3L I4, the 5.0L V8 was sold with it but the car was an I4 from the factory, so it lacks the stronger brakes, suspension, etc. -- The engine would be a drop-in/bolt-up to the current T5, but it would be far from safe.)

---

The car has basically no interior. (The stock top half of the dash is present, where the gauge cluster, light controls, etc. are housed. That's about it.)

I'm looking to MacGyver the interior while I work on the mechanical pieces that need attention. My intent was to source and cut-out some carpet, and glue it down with some [weaker] adhesive so it won't be *too* permanent when I revisit the interior next year.

One problem with this plan is: the engine management computer is in the passenger cab, in the very front right corner of the car. (If you were riding in the passenger seat, it is located where your right foot would be.)

The wiring harness and computer is completely exposed, and the grounding strap *doesn't really ground to anything.*

Given that I live in Wisconsin, and people tend to have snow and mud on their boots, this is not going to work in the long term.

I'm not sure where it was originally mounted, or if there's a missing piece of trim that was meant to cover it, but I need a solution to keep it safe from stray boots.

Is anyone familiar with the '89-93 Mustang that could share some insight?
The OEM mounting hardware might be non-existent on this car, so creative answers for protecting the ECU would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the car, but could you not create a temporary cover/box out of some light plastic or aluminium sheet? Either stuck down in the same way as the carpet (although I personally wouldn't bother with carpet at this stage, get the important bits done first and worry about that later...), or screwed to the bulkhead either side of the ECU.

I suspect that originally it would have been enclosed within the lower part of the dashboard, probably with a clip-in removable cover for access.

Comment: Turns out that it is mounted in its standard location.

Its meant to be covered by a kick panel; which is held in by willpower and _other_ passenger door trimmings.

So I think a temporary cover is in order until the weather warms up and I can dumpster dive for the necessary bits.

Light plastic sounds like a good option to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the EEC-III or EEC-IV or later CPU mounted originally in the passenger kick panel by the door? If so, those computers are inside of cast metal and almost impervious to dirt, etc.

If you want to keep water, mud, snow off of it, you should be able to just rivet an aluminum shield next to it. That would probably keep people from stepping on or next to it. It probably doesn't have to be completely waterproof. The large connector I believe is also water resistant.